# job shop scheduling using python

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, job-scheduling, tabu-search

I'm working on a project related to solving the job shop scheduling problem using Tabu search, genetic algorithms, or any suitable algorithm in Python. I've referred to this GitHub repository: https://github.com/mcfadd/Job_Shop_Schedule_Problem.git, but I've been unable to install it. Could someone please try installing it to see if it works?

Also, if you know of any libraries that can be used to solve this problem, could you please introduce them to me? Thank you very much

i'm new to python and programming, so please help me to install and deploy this successfully

Comment: the provided link returns 404 error

Comment: i'm so sorry here the work one: https://github.com/mcfadd/Job_Shop_Schedule_Problem.git

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.